# Check length of field in a text file with delimiter

Tags: bash

My goal is to check the length of the third field of each line of a text file.  The third field must be a numeric string of 8 characters and in the output i would like to have all the line where third field length is different from 8 and are not numeric

Example:

```
Terry;18;44123456;yes
Mark;19;44098711;no
Sandy;19;4411897090;no
Tom;17;4413;no
```

Output:

```
Sandy;19;4411897090;no
Tom;17;4412;no
```

I've tried with:

```
awk -F, '{if(length($3) == 8 ) print }'
```

but I can't achieve my goal.  How should I proceed?

SOLUTION:

```
awk -F, '{if(length($3) != 8 ) print }'
```

THanks everybody for helping me. Still the better community so far

Comment: No field of `Tom;17;4412;no` is length 8, but it should be included in the output?  Huh?

Comment: Your sample output is the opposite of what you say you want. You say you want the lines where field 3 is 8 characters, but the output is the lines where it's _not_ 8 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command uses a comma as the FS `-F,` and your example uses a semicolon as a delimiter.

Lines with third field eight characters.

```
awk -F\; 'length($3) == 8'
```

Lines with third field NOT eight characters.

```
awk -F\; 'length($3) != 8'
```

Lines with third field NOT eight characters OR third field not an integer.

```
awk -F\; 'length($3) != 8 || $3 + 0 != $3'
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work, you have to escape the ';'

```
awk -F\; '{if(length($3) == 8 ) print }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your field separator (`-F`) for `awk` should be `;` not `,`

Answer (score 1):

You can use good old `grep` since it is meant for this kind of work:

```
grep '[^;]\+;[^;]\+;[[:digit:]]\{8\}' file
```

... or even simpler:

```
egrep '[^;]+;[^;]+;[[:digit:]]{8}' file
```

or:

```
egrep '([^;]+;){2}[[:digit:]]{8}' file
```

Comment: Why are you matching a literal `+`? And shouldn't `[^,]` be `[^;]`?

Comment: @Barmar `grep` is using basic POSIX regexes. The `+` (when used as a quantifier) needs to get escaped.

Comment: @Barmar But thanks for the hint with the `,` which should have been a `;` :) !! .. Was a typo..

Comment: @user2302636 What does "working" mean if it's not already filtering the output?

Comment: I don't get your comments. What do you expect the output should look like?

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
awk -F\; 'length($3)!=8' file
```

`print`and `if`statement can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks for improving my choice! but how can i filter the output with "wrong" lines?

Comment: just negate the condition, see my ed. answer

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
grep "^[^;]*;[^;]*;[0-9]\{8\};[^;]*$" file.txt
```